# How can I get Cypress to run a specific folder of tests by specifying it as a project?

Tags: javascript, command-line, cypress

I have the following directory structure for working with Cypress:

```
cypress-automation
    cypress
        fixtures
        integration
           apps
              pulse
              smhw-prod
              smhw-qa
                  folder-a
                       sample-spec.js
        examples
        plugins
        screenshots
        support
        videos
        node_modules
        cypress.json // this is where the file currently is
        package-lock.json
        package.json
```

**Expectation**

What I want to do is run all the tests inside the `smhw-qa` folder (there are a number of spec files in there) .. and be able to pass this using the `--project` command using CLI.

Currently if I just run `--run`` without any other arguments all the spec files, from all folders will start to run which is not desirable, since there are multiple applications "projects" (smhw-qa, smhw-prod etc) within this structure. This will allow me to only run the spec files from a single folder as desired.

I am also aware of using the `--run` command to "run" a specific folder, but I want to use "projects" instead to organise these tests so it's easier to identify them later.

I have had a look at the docs which show the use of the `--project` command however I need to help to understand what else I need to setup in order to make this work. By this, I am referring to the `package.json` file.

**What I tried so far**
I tried to follow the example provided for testing "nested folders" from here:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-test-nested-projects

`package.json`: added the following script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "smhw-qa": "cypress run --project ./cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa"
  },
```

When I run this via the terminal like so:

```
➜  cypress-automation npx cypress run --project ./cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa
```

I get an error:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files inside of this folder:

/Users/jaswindersingh/Documents/cypress-automation/cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa/cypress/integration
```

Am I missing something? Should my `cypress.json` file be located elsewhere?

I'd like to be able to set each of the folders inside "apps" to be projects, and then be able to run these projects using the `cypress run --project` command.

This will also make it easier to run specific folders of tests when I hookup our CI so that only specific projects (and their spec files) run when I choose.

Comment: The `--project` flag is used to point to your `cypress.json` being located in a different directory.  I don't use this, but that's what I understand from the docs here:  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-project-lt-project-path-gt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group together certain tests or files when doing a run in Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634961/how-to-group-together-certain-tests-or-files-when-doing-a-run-in-cypress)

Comment: See this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119398/is-there-any-way-to-run-cypress-open-and-only-include-test-files-containing-a-ke

Answer (score 65):

I think you're looking for `--spec path/to/folder/*.js`

You can run all the tests in a folder, or even in all subfolders of a folder,

ex/ `npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/subsetA/**/*-spec.js`

would run all .js specs in all folders under the "subsetA" folder in cypress/integration.

So in your case: `npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa/**/*-spec.js` should do the trick.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#How-to-run-commands

Comment: Don't forget to use " (double quotes) to specify file name. For example `npx cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa/**/*-spec.js"`. Otherwise it may not work (for me it failed while running this on linux pipeline, even if in my windows local machine worked at first :) )

Comment: @notihs I suspect this depends on who expands the `**`.  In your linux case, it could have been the shell so the `npx` command "saw" multiple files passed to it; in Windows the shell doesn't do that, so `npx` "saw" the "**" and expanded it like it needs.

Comment: Just a small typo: `cypresss` => `cypress` (one 's' less)

Comment: @jnotelddim, could you help here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71613297/get-code-coverage-only-for-a-folder-in-cypress

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have angular workspace with multiple projects in it and I moved the cypress folder and cypress.json file in this sub project eg `./projects/app1`.

Then add `"integrationFolder": "e2e/cypress/integration",` in the configuration file to specify tests directory.

Add these scripts to package.json

`cypress open --project ./projects/app1`

`cypress run --project ./projects/app1`

And only tests from `e2e/cypress/integration` directory are executed or opened.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with running all tests files from one directory with

```
"cypress run --headed --no-exit --spec 'cypress/integration/sometests/*'"
```

Cypress was running only the first test file and stoppeded.

I've tried all combinations with *.js, *-spec.js etc and the problem was with the --no-exit flag. Removing --no-exit solved my problem.

Also, I've noticed that the path should be in quotes according to cypress docs https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#How-to-run-commands

Answer (score 0):

use the next command if you need run specs from different folders, or several folders simultaneously:

```
"cypress run --record --key=your-key-if-needed --spec cypress/e2e/folder1/**/*,cypress/e2e/folder2/**/*.cy.js,cypress/e2e/folder3/**/*.cy.js"
```

instead of ** you could specify spec subfolder or spec name