# How to group together certain tests or files when doing a run in Cypress?

Tags: automation, e2e-testing, cypress

I am currently running Cypress and I have folders inside of it, where I have tests located for different applications. 
I have a folder entitled "smhw-qa" which contains sub-folders and tests files for this specific application.

This directory `apps` will also include other applications too in future.

## What I wish to do

In order to avoid having to run **every** test for a run, I wish to only run this specific folder. The location of the folder is as such:

```
'cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa'
```

Over time, there will be more folders and tests added to the `apps` directory.

I **am** familiar with how to run a specific file, so doing the following works:

```
npx cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa/banners_promos_global/global_search.js'
```

**How can I specify to Cypress which folder to run specifically when I use the `npx cypress -run` command?**

## What I have tried already

To run a specific test file I tried:

```
npx cypress run --project 'cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa'
```

But this provides an error instead:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files inside of this folder:

/Users/jaswindersingh/Documents/cypress-automation/automation/cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa/cypress/integration
```

Running specific sets of tests by their folders will be much easier for me, and will save time when running a specific suite of tests on our CI platform for example. I will also not need to specify the individual files since this is time-consuming.

It would also mean I can split out my tests and run them on different machines

Do I need to put anything into my test files, or inside of `cypress.json` or modify anything else, or can this be achieved through the terminal? 
What options must I use instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the clue is in the error message, you call

```
cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa
```

and the error message shows

```
cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa/cypress/integration
```

so to use the `--project` flag you need to replicate the `/cypress` folder per project, as per this example [cypress-test-nested-projects](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-test-nested-projects)

**Folder structure:**

```
package.json
node_modules
src/
    clients/
        foo/
            cypress.json
            cypress/
        bar/
            cypress.json
            cypress/
```

---

However, I think you might want to use the `--spec` flag instead. If I understand it correctly, the glob pattern will allow you to keep the current folder structure. [Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-spec-lt-spec-gt)

```
cypress run --spec 'cypress/integration/apps/smhw-qa/**/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Through `--project` you can manage different cypress.json files, the docs says

> This enables you to install Cypress in a top level node_modules folder but run Cypress in a nested folder. This is also helpful when you have multiple Cypress projects in your repo.

so you're on the right way, just prepare some project-related `cypress.json` files