# Is there any way to run cypress open and only include test files containing a key word? eg. lifecycle from domains-lifecycle.spec.jsx

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I have a fairly large library of test files in my project (roughly 80) and I have them named with keywords ex. "create" "Edit" and "lifecycle". I want to be able to run `npx cypress open` and only include all the test files that contain "lifecycle" for example. Is there something I can add to the Cypress.json globing wise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on @JosePita's idea, you can set up glob patterns in scripts (package.json) and by-pass the multitude config files he was concerned about.

For example, these work on my system,

```js
"scripts": {
  "cy:open": "cypress open",                              // all files
  "cy:user": "cypress open -c testFiles=user/**/*",       // just the user folder
  "cy:error": "cypress open -c testFiles=**/*error*.js",  // files with keyword 'error'
```

---

There's a search bar at the top of the Cypress runner, where the tests are listed, but search is all it does.

Pressing the **Run all specs** button runs the full set regardless of search results.

If you want to ***run*** a subset, specify the `testFiles` config option on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-open) it seems you can open it using a config file and from [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Folders-Files) you can configure what files to load on the configuration.

It's an ugly solution because you'd need to have multiple config files for all the keywords you need (and maintain them).

Another option is to have your test files separated by folders, each with it's own cypress project inside ([docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-open-project-lt-project-path-gt) and [example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-test-nested-projects))

Comment: Scroll up on your first link, you find `cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/login/**/*"` which by-passes the config files, which uses a glob pattern so chances are you can work keywords into that. Some example code would be good.

Comment: @eric99 he asked for `cypress open` , not `cypress run`

Comment: oh yeah, if cypress run works for him (actually it makes more sense to run the tests the same way you would in the CI), it's perfect