# Get code coverage only for a folder in Cypress

Tags: next.js, cypress, nyc

I am using Cypress and Nyc configurations. My folder structure looks like this:

```html
|/project
| /coverage/
   /lcov-report
    /index.html
 
|/cypress
| /main
   /car
    /car.spec.tsx
    /color.spec.tsx
     ...
| /integration
```

I need a solution to get inside the `index.html` only the tests coverage from `main` folder. So as a result in `index.html` i need to see only the coverage for the tests that was written there.

 I noticed that NYC docs. have some configurations https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#common-configuration-options . But there i can specifiy only the files that contains features in `include`, but in each folder from my project i could have a test file and i can not specify every time the each new file only to get the coverage. 
 Question: Is there a solution to get the coverage only for the `main` folder or to get the coverage for the files that have already written a `spec` test? Or to get a coverage for the file that have `spec.tsx` extension?

Comment: @user16695029, could you help?

Comment: What does "But there i can specifiy only the files that contains features in include" mean?

Comment: @kegne, I mean that according documentation i can specify the files that contain the files with code implementation, not with tests, so i can not specify in `include` for example the files with `spec.tsx` because they contain only tests. This is how i understood. Do i understand correct?

Comment: Surely you select a subset of ***tests*** in the Cypress configuration?

Comment: @kegne, what do you mean?

Comment: Your explanation is not at all clear, but this ***so i can not specify in include for example the files with spec.tsx*** implies you want to select tests not code files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243313/discussion-between-asking-and-kegne).

Comment: @kegne, i need the coverage only for these file which i have written test. So i need the coverage only for these tests that are located in `main` folder. Please let me know if you understood.

Comment: @kegne, could you help? It will save my day.

Comment: So you written two test for only some of the src files, you want coverage only for those src files?

Comment: @Vispo Yes, all may tests are in `main` folder from `/cypress` folder. So, yes, i need the coverage only for these files that have tests. But i don't want to specific the  list of the files in `include: []`  being hardcoded, i want somehow to get the coverage report only for the tests that are in `main` folder. Could you help please? It will help me a lot.

Comment: Could you help?

Comment: The obvious thing is just run the tests in main. But the premise of your question is flawed - Cypress tests **are not unit tests**, there is no 1:1 between test and src. You have to take whatever code-coverage sees when it runs your tests.

Comment: @Vispo, so i can not get only the test coverage for the tests that was written in `main`?

Answer (score 6):

Please read the documentation, from the above page chose the link to [Selecting files for coverage](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#selecting-files-for-coverage).

> Globs are matched using minimatch.

Cypress explains minimatch [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/minimatch#Examples).

It's the same as many other places in javascript you will have seen files specified

```js
include: [ '/main/**']
```

Comment: this `include` means that will set the coverage only for the tests that was written in `main` folder? I ask you because i understand that `include` means that in the coverage will be included the files that contain features but not tests. So can i add there the `spec.tsx` files?